# Deriving formula for curvature of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, curvature

I am trying to prove that given a parametric function of a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the curvature of the curve for each $\gamma(t)$ is given by the following expression :

$$k(t)=\frac{\sqrt{||\gamma’(t)||^2||\gamma’’(t)||^2-(\gamma’(t)\cdot\gamma’’(t))^2}}{||\gamma’(t)||^3}$$

I have tried to use an arc-length parametrization of the curve but it leads me nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use arclength parametrization.  We have $\gamma'(t)=s'(t)T(t)$, where $T(t)$ is the unit tangent vector and from the definition of the Frenet frame in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we also have $\gamma''(t)=s''(t)T(t) + s'(t)^2\kappa(t)P_1(t)$, where $P_1(t)$ is the first normal vector in the $n$-dimensional Frenet frame.

Since $\{T,P_1\}$ is an orthonormal set,  $\|\gamma'\|^2 = (s')^2$ and $\gamma'\cdot\gamma''=s's''$ and also $\|\gamma''\|^2=(s'')^2+(s')^4\kappa^2$ .  The quantity you have under your square root comes out to
\begin{equation}
(s')^2(s'')^2+(s')^6\kappa^2-(s')^2(s'')^2=(s')^6\kappa^2.
\end{equation}
The result you are looking for follows.

There are nice formulas for all higher curvatures.  You could check out Section 9.1 in *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* by Banchoff and Lovett, 2nd edition. (The first edition does not have Chapter 9, so you need 2nd ed. or higher.)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing truly insightful: just a lot of computations. Reparameterize $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\circ \Phi$ is arc-length parameterized.  This yields:

\begin{equation}
\langle \alpha'(\Phi(u))\Phi'(u), \alpha'(\Phi(u))\Phi'(u) \rangle=1
\label{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\langle \alpha''(\Phi(u))\Phi'(u)^2+\alpha'(\Phi(u))\Phi''(u), \alpha'(\Phi(u))\Phi'(u) \rangle=0
\label{2}
\end{equation}

The first relation also implies the two following equations:

\begin{equation}
\Phi'(u)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\langle\alpha'(\Phi(u)),\alpha'(\Phi(u))\rangle}}=\frac{1}{|\alpha'(\Phi(u)|}
\end{equation}

$$\Phi''(u)=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\langle \alpha'(\Phi(u)),\alpha'(\Phi(u))\rangle^{\frac{3}{2}
}}2\langle \alpha'(\Phi(u)),\alpha''(\Phi(u))\rangle\Phi'(u)=-\frac{\langle \alpha'(\Phi(u)),\alpha''(\Phi(u))\rangle}{|\alpha'(\Phi(u))|^4}$$

With these four equations, we are ready to prove the main result. First let us introduce the variable $\Gamma=\alpha''(\Phi(u))\Phi'(u)^2+\alpha'(\Phi(u))\Phi''(u)$:

$$ |k|^2=|(\alpha(\Phi(u)))''|^2=|\Gamma|^2=\langle\Gamma,\alpha''(\Phi(u))\rangle\Phi'(u)^2+\langle\Gamma,\alpha'(\Phi(u))\rangle\Phi''(u)$$

By the second equation we have $ \langle\Gamma,\alpha'(\Phi(u))\rangle\Phi''(u)=0$ (because it is a regular parametrization and we may multiply and divide by $\Phi'(u)$). Thus:

$$k^2=\langle\Gamma,\alpha''(\Phi(u))\rangle\Phi'(u)^2=$$
$$\langle\alpha''(\Phi(u)),\alpha''(\Phi(u))\rangle\Phi'(u)^4+\langle \alpha'(\Phi(u)),\alpha''(\Phi(u))\rangle\Phi''(u)\Phi'(u)^2=$$
$$\frac{|\alpha''(\Phi(u))|^2}{|\alpha'(\Phi(u))|^4}-\frac{\langle \alpha'(\Phi(u)),\alpha''(\Phi(u))\rangle^2}{|\alpha'(\Phi(u))|^6}$$

Taking the square root from both sides yields:

$$k=\frac{\sqrt{|\alpha''(\Phi(u))|^2|\alpha'(\Phi(u))|^2-\langle \alpha'(\Phi(u)),\alpha''(\Phi(u))\rangle^2}}{|\alpha'(\Phi(u))|^3}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{|\alpha''(t)|^2|\alpha'(t)|^2-\langle \alpha'(t),\alpha''(t)\rangle^2}}{|\alpha'(t)|^3}$$

Comment: In addition to not re-using OPs notation, none of the terms and functions are defined α, Φ etc neither their domains, this makes it really hard to read the answer, at least to me.

Comment: @arkan, I will try to help you. $\alpha: I \subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is your curve. However, you have no guarantee that $|\alpha'|\equiv 1$, you  only know $|\alpha'|$  is not zero anywhere (by definition of a regular curve). Let me define $\Phi^*=\int_0^s |\alpha'|$. This function is invertible and we will call its inverse $\Phi$ (try differentiating $\Phi^*$ and using the Inverse Function Theorem). When you write $\alpha \circ \Phi$ we have $(\alpha\circ \Phi)'\equiv 1$. If any step is not that clear feel free to enquire further.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, this is very helpful. I have questions though. Let $s(t) = \alpha(t)$; My understanding is that the curvature is $s''(\Phi(t))$ it can be shown that $\kappa=s''(\Phi(t))=\frac{\|{T'(t)}\|}{\|{ s'(t)}\|}=\frac{\left\|\frac{s'(t)}{\|s'(t)\|}\right\|}{\|s'(t)\|}=\frac{ \|{s'(t) \times  s''(t)}\|}{{\|s'(t)\|}^3}$ .  But I don't understand the starting point.  When you say "Consider the reparametrization  $\alpha\circ \Phi$, this yields to dot product=1; dot product=0" I don't see where those dot product come from.

Comment: After some reverse engineering I guess it comes from: (1) $\|s'(\Phi(t)) \|^2=1$ and (2) $< (s(\Phi(t)))'', s'(\Phi(t))>=0$. I understand (1) as "we must enforce velocity equal 1" in other words $\Phi$ must be an arc length parametrization. As for (2) it is like stating "velocity and acceleration must be perpendicular" which is puzzling, I don't understand why we should enforce such thing to compute the curvature. So yea, I don't understand why the starting point is not the definition of the curvature $k = s''$

Comment: The problem with your line of reasoning is that $||(\alpha \circ \Phi)’||^2=1$. So you need the chain rule to compute the derivative. Saying that $||\alpha’\circ \Phi||^2=1$ wouldn’t be correct.

Comment: Sorry, I made notation mistake in my previous comments, It should be: $k = (s(\Phi(t))''$; (1) $\| (s(\Phi(t)))' \|^2=1$ and (2) $< (s(\Phi(t))'', (s(\Phi(t))'>=0$ etc. So you confirm that (1) and (2) are your starting point? I still don't see why? Especially for (2). By the way I was able to derive myself the traditional $\frac{ \|{s'(t) \times  s''(t)}\|}{{\|s'(t)\|}^3}$ with chain rule. But I'd like to understand other notations like in your post and where this other result $k(t)=\frac{\sqrt{||\gamma’(t)||^2||\gamma’’(t)||^2-(\gamma’(t)\cdot\gamma’’(t))^2}}{||\gamma’(t)||^3}$ comes from.